# Why destructor is automatically called in case of new operator?

Tags: c++, destructor, new-operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class Foo {
public:
    uint32_t m_Size;
    char *m_Data;

public:
    Foo() = default;

    Foo(const char *pieceOfString) {
        printf("Foo Created!\n");
        m_Size = strlen(pieceOfString);
        m_Data = new char[m_Size];
        memcpy(m_Data, pieceOfString, m_Size);
    }

    ~Foo() {
        printf("Deleted Foo. ");
        delete[] this->m_Data;
    }
};

class Entity {
public:
    Foo m_Name;

public:
    Entity(const Foo &name){
        this->m_Name=name;
    }

    ~Entity(){
        printf("Deleted entity. ");
    }
};


int main() {

    Foo* apple=new Foo("something");
    Entity entity=Entity(*apple);


    return 0;
}
```

As the result of the code above, my console output was:

```
Foo Created!
Deleted Entity. Deleted Foo.
```

If a new object is created with the `new` operator, `delete` or `delete[]` operator has to be used in order to free the corresponding memory blocks of the heap. In my example below, I had not used the `delete` keyword to destruct `Foo` object (which was created by new), however the destructors of the classes were executed properly. I suppose the automatic destruction of the `entity` object involves calling the destruction of `apple` as it is a member of `entity`. But I am not sure about it.

If I write **delete apple**, it gives me `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`.

Any help is appreciated!

---

### Answer:

After making some research and reading the comments, I can answer my question: Why destructor is automatically called in case of new operator? The destructor is not automatically called in case of new operator. In the example there is a variable created on the stack called `entity`. Because it goes out of scope, first its user-defined destructor is called. That is why `Deleted Entity` is written on console. After that, it continues to destruct the members. There is only one with Foo type and Foo class has also got a user defined destructor. That is why `Deleted Foo` appears on the output and the block on the heap pointed by `entity.m_Name.m_Data` is freed up due to `delete[] this->m_Data;` as it is also in the destructor. Because the apple object and the `m_Name` member of the entity points to the same place, calling `delete apple;` was indicating `free(): double free detected in tcache 2`. So the user-defined destructors of Foo and Entity were called due to the stack allocated `entity` was going out of scope.

---

However, this case must be avoided as the example violates the rule of three: The `apple` object and the `m_Name` member of the entity points to the same place.

Comment: It isn't. `Foo m_Name;` creates a new object. And that object is not allocated with `new`.

Comment: You violate the rule of 3/5/0. The `m_data` object in `apple` and `entity` point at the same memory. The `entity` destructor will delete it. `delete apple` will also delete it, but not calling `delete apple` will leak that memory.

Comment: The code changed a bit since my last comment so I deleted. This is a violation of the rule of 3/5/0: Related: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Bizarre!  `Deleted String.` isn't even in the code, I have no idea why that would have been output to the console.

Comment: I think the output matches the first code posted. There was code that was changed in the initial edit window that does not show up as revision 1. The initial code was simpler. I think only a std::string member for Foo

Comment: Note that the output messages are incorrect; nothing here gets deleted, so the code ought to report "Destroyed Foo. " and "Destroyed Entity. ".

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm But if I call "delete apple", it gives me "double free detected error". So i suppose the user defined destructor of apple is already called.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, there was a misspelling in the console output. I corrected "Destroyed String" to "Destroyed Foo". But in the destructor of Foo there is delete[] this->m_Data; as I am creating m_Data with new operator.

Comment: I will check the rule of 3/5/0. Thanks!

Comment: @Tom -- in case I was too subtle, my point was about the difference between "Deleted xxx" and "Destroyed xxx". In the destructor you know that the object is being destroyed. That could be because it was created with `new` and then deleted, but it could also be because it was created on the stack and simply went out of scope, with no `delete`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Now I clearly recognized what the problem was.